# Getting Value from Dynamic Url and Post it into HTML/PHP by Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5

I would like to ask whether I can get the data from dynamic URL... Here is the case:

1. I have given an (a) html tag into my angularJS php file to give direction to certain page with the value inside it e.g. `localhost:8080/someurl/blablabla/{{item.master}}` so the output is based on what I have clicked... so it will be `localhost:8080/someurl/blablabla/221`
2. After that, I have a laravel 5.2 and given a route based on this dynamic url, e.g. `Route::get('order/{id}','someController@index')`
3. After this route, I have prepared the php files and it is ready to display the data

The problem is, I don't know which angularJS code that I should use to display the data based on the `{{item.master}}` in this new page, when I use `$http.get`, it doesn't get anything, is there any clue about this?

UPDATED

Here is the codes:

1. HTML (order.html)

   ```
   <div class="itemcheck" ng-repeat="item in dataItem.stores | regex:'name':alfabet | orderBy: 'name' | filter: searchItem" ng-model="item">
   <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == ''" ng-click="klikItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-circle silver"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '1'" ng-click="klikItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-circle green"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
    <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '2'" ng-click="klikItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-circle yellow"></i>{{item.name}}</div>
   <div class="left" ng-if="item.preparation == '3'" ng-click="klikItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-circle pink"></i>{{item.name}}</div> <div class="right" ng-click="tambahItem(item)"><a>+ Tambahkan</a></div></div>
   ```

Let's not focus on "tambahkan" but the item.name when I put klikItem function

So, when I click, the klikItem() function is triggered (what I want) or let's say I put the tag a inside the {{item.name}} function and when I click that it goes to order/{{item.id}} (somehow like that)...

Nah, the problem is, how can I get the data from order/{{item.id}}? If I use $http.get, it must have the data, and when I put id for example

```
$scope.tampilkanDeskripsiItem = function(id){
        var url = 'order/' + id;
        $http.get(url).success(function(data){
            $scope.deskripsiItem = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.tampilkanDeskripsiItem();
```

this code will return error as "id" is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id inside klikItem (if item object has id property.)

```
function klikItem(item){
   $scope.tampilkanDeskripsiItem(item.id);
}
```